# Creating relationship in sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relationship

Suppose i have 2 table where pid and id is primary key and auto increment

1. posting containing column

   ```
   pid | post|
   ```
2. linking containing column

   ```
   id | pid | name
   ```

and i when to fetch post data(assume i know the [name] and i want to fetch postid)

i can do this in php using two loop like

```
$b=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT pid FROM linking WHERE name='bla'")
while($a=mysqli_fetch_array($b)){
    $c=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT post FROM posting WHERE pid='$a["pid"]' LIMIT 1"))
}
```

But i know there is better way to do that using relationship in sql if anyone can help me with query

i look but find something inner join that i didnt understand

Comment: Maybe rather use a join and fetch all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT pid FROM linking
JOIN SELECT posting on linking.pid=posting.pid
 WHERE linking.name='bla'
```

And if you'd like only the first row of the second table you might do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM linking
  LEFT JOIN posting a ON posting.pid = (
    SELECT
      MIN(posting.pid) pid2
    FROM posting p2
    WHERE p2.pid2 = linking.pid
  )
WHERE Linking.name='bla'
```

Comment: in 1 this --->#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT posting on linking.pid=posting.pid WHERE linking.name='bla' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2         ,,,,,     in 2nd query--->>>>Unknown column 'posting.pid' in 'on clause'

Comment: I've edited it now, but instead of just copy-pasting it I'd suggest you try to understand the query and adapt it to your own requirements.